# Converting Java Object to Fixed length flat file creation

Tags: java

Example - Student Objects have Name, age, address and Marks

Flat file should have pre define space and padding

Entity and corresponding Length -

```
Name - 5
Age - 2
Address - 9
Marks -2
```

Output- flat file

```
Mike 23London   99
Ley  24NYK      98
```

Any framework or suggestions to handle huge data from object to flat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` to format each line of the output, e.g.

```
printWriter.printf("%-5s%2d%-9s%2d%n", name, age, address, marks)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !. Is this a efficient way for huge number of date/file or is there any other way around

Comment: @GopalHaldar Try it for yourself. Only empirical evidence will tell you if performance is an issue. This is the best/simplest way to format values in fixed columns. Don't waste time trying more complex alternatives unless you determine that performance isn't good enough, and that the performance problem is caused by this statement. Doing it another way is unlikely to gain a lot of performance, at the potential loss of code clarity.